# subtracting two pointers(arrays), (C language)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int vector[] = { 28, 41, 7 };
int *p0 = vector;
int *p1 = vector + 1;
int *p2 = vector + 2;
```

I know result of

`printf("%p, %p, %p\n", p0, p1, p2);`

is ex) `100, 104, 108`

but why is the result of

```
printf("p2-p0: %d\n", p2 - p0);
printf("p2-p1: %d\n", p2 - p1);
printf("p0-p1: %d\n", p0 - p1);
```

is `2, 1, -1`

not `8, 4, -4`????????

Comment: Do you know what is the data type of the result of pointer difference? If you do, you should not use %d in printf...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you subtract to pointers (of the same type else no sense) that computes the difference as indexes, not the difference of the addresses :

```
type * p1 = ...;
type * p2 = ...;
(p1 - p2) == (((char *) p1) - ((char *) p2)) / sizeof(type)
```

It is the same when you do `vector + n`, that gives the address of the  element rank *n*, not `((char *) vector) + n`. So

```
type * p = ...;
int n = ...;

((char *) (p + n)) == (((char *) p) + n * sizeof(type))
```